# Why is my Areca palm dying

Tags: houseplants, indoors

I've bought this Areca palm in Ikea about a month ago. It was doing fine for a week or so, and then, suddenly, leaves started turning yellow, then black. At first I thought it was normal, since only the bottom leaves were drying, but now the top leaves and the middle ones are also turning yellow - brown - black. Also, if you notice, the plant is not straight anymore, like all the leaves are falling down. I would like to know what am I missing here, I've been watering it once a week, everytime the soil is dried out. Also, I've been sprinkling it with water every couple of days. The temperature of the room is about 25 degrees Celsius, it is near the window.I haven't noticed any spots on the bottom side of the leaves. I would like to know what to do next, since I love this plant very much and i hate to see it dying this way :'(

These are the photos of it when i bought it:

https://ibb.co/KjWz7Ys

https://ibb.co/563fhp8

This is the plant now:

https://ibb.co/9V1J5CN

https://ibb.co/rp6JvDq

https://ibb.co/Zz2hWpf

https://ibb.co/rwtFvN5

https://ibb.co/7nbkwxs

https://ibb.co/gDbjKsq

Comment: post images properly

Answer (score 1):

Does your local water authority put fluoride in the water? If so you may be inadvertently contributing to this issue. In this [helpful factsheet from University of Florida](https://mrec.ifas.ufl.edu/foliage/folnotes/areca.htm) they give some details about keeping the right soil pH, plus watching the addition of salts to the watering solution.