# Sambac jasmin drying out

Tags: plant-health, leaves, plant-care, watering, dryness

## BACKGROUND

I have a jasmin plant (jasminum sambac).

- Up until about a month ago it was full of green leaves, and had scented white flowers blooming
- About a month ago many of its leaves started yellowing and drying out, and now there aren't that many left
- I cut the dry yellow leaves off, thinking it was stress related, and hoping the plant would be better in time

#### INFO

- **Light conditions**: plenty of sun
- **Water conditions**: soil is moist when I put my finger in. Looks like it retains water properly, almost like it's "not drinking" the water. It's currently lightly watered once a week (to avoid root rot)

I also thought about water purity issues ([see this question](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/43146/why-is-my-areca-palm-dying)) or soil volume might not suffice ([see this question](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/47892/passiflora-snow-queen-is-drying-out)), but all the other plants enjoy the same water and they're fine, and the soil volume is about 5 times bigger than the pot it initially grew to be this size in.

## ISSUE

Now the last leaves also started drying out, and the stems feel like they're drying out too.

How can I save it before it's too late?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Info

I still can't say what was caused it dry out.

The plant leaves turned all yellow, and they all dropped - leaving it totally bare. Luckily it wasn't dead yet.

## Actions

I treated the plant with home-made "soup", which I make from my own home-made compost and my own home-made humus solution.

I kept watering the "dead" plant for 6 months after all the leaves fell out with a water/"soup" mixture (about 1:9 ratio of soup:water)

It took about 6 months to get it to start growing back again, after it looked all dried out from the outside.

## Possible causes

I'm guessing that multiple causes, all at the same time, caused it to dry out:

1. The "shock" of replanting and moving it to diffident growing conditions (growing medium, lighting conditions, etc.)
2. The new location is has more wind and is possibly less humid
3. Possible seasonal effects
4. Though it was planted in fresh soil, it's possible the soil had insufficient nutrient capacity, which was restored with the "soup".

## Currently

I pruned and trimmed most of the plant, leaving only a handful of stems at the base.

It started growing again, and grew roughly 70[cm] in a few weeks (see image).

[image: jasmine-after]

Answer (score 0):

As per the second question you linked to, the issue is likely the size of the container it's growing in - *Jasminum sambac* is a large, evergreen, scrambling plant, with a height and spread of 2.5-4 metres, with a spread up to 1.5 metres in the ground. In order to grow properly, the plant needs to form quite a widespread and deep root system as it matures, which it cannot do contained in a shallow trough.

You don't say where you are, but this plant is not entirely hardy - it will tolerate down to about 4 degrees C, but frost will kill it. Assuming you live somewhere warm enough, if you cannot transfer it to the ground, then you can keep it going for a few more years by transferring it to a large pot, something 2 feet deep by at least 12-18 inches wide. It will still eventually start to fail when it runs out of root room again, but you should get another 4/5 or more years of good growth out of it in a larger pot.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Bamboo, in the end I kept the Jasmine in the same container. I don't think the size of the container was the issue, but I will definitely consider container size for the future.